# VB.NET Add Any EventHandler Type with Delegate

Tags: vb.net, events, reflection, delegates, eventhandler

I've found a few posts (not many) that I thought might solve my problem but in all my reading I still don't have a solution.

What I'm trying to do is basically create a method that will bind any given control's event to any given object's method using `Reflection.EventInfo` and `Reflection.MethodInfo`. I'm using Winforms, I'd love to just use WPF but that's not an option unfortunately.

I have an abstract `BoundControl` class that is just an empty canvas for inherited controls. In that class is the function below:

```
Public Sub CallMethod(eventName As String, sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
...
End Sub
```

This is what I want to be called whenever a given control's event is raised. The logic in that method calls the correct method on the data context (I've set this up to mimic WPF). This is working fine, my problem is actually binding the above method to a control's event.

I bind using the method below (in the same class as the method above). Note that I've removed the unimportant logic, stuff like my custom binding tag class and anything else unrelated to my problem:

```
Public Sub SetEventBind(ByRef ctrl as Control)
    Dim ctrlStr As String = "EventName"
    Dim ctrlEvent as Reflection.EventInfo = ctrl.GetType.GetEvent(ctrlStr)
    Dim eh As EventHandler = (Sub(sender, e) CallMethod(ctrlStr, sender, e))
    ctrlEvent.AddEventHandler(ctrl, eh)
End Sub
```

I'm trying to run my code on a `LinkLabel` for the `LinkClicked` event but I want this to work for any control's events. What ends up happening is `EventHandler` type cannot be converted to `LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler`. So just to test I tried the code below and it DID work:

```
Public Sub SetEventBind(ByRef ctrl as Control)
    Dim ctrlStr As String = "EventName"
    Dim ctrlEvent as Reflection.EventInfo = ctrl.GetType.GetEvent(ctrlStr)
    Dim eh As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler = (Sub(sender, e) CallMethod(ctrlStr, sender, e))
    ctrlEvent.AddEventHandler(ctrl, eh)
End Sub
```

But the problem is `LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler` won't work for, say, a button click or a checkbox checked change. I also tried the code below and it didn't work:

```
Public Sub SetEventBind(ByRef ctrl as Control)
    Dim ctrlStr As String = "EventName"
    Dim ctrlEvent as Reflection.EventInfo = ctrl.GetType.GetEvent(ctrlStr)
    Dim eh As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(ctrlevent.EventHandlerType, Me, (Sub(sender, e) CallMethod(ctrlStr, sender, e)).Method)
    ctrlEvent.AddEventHandler(ctrl, eh)
End Sub
```

I guess my question is multi-part. I think if I could dynamically create a delegate of the same type as `ctrlEvent.EventHandlerType` then I could get this working. Is it possible to dynamically set variable's type? If not, is there another way to dynamically bind any control's event to a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article that was helpful (below). What I had to do was create a separate function that would convert and return a delegate to the correct delegate type.

```
Public Sub SetEventBind(ByRef ctrl As IBoundControl, pBindingTag As BindingTag, pDoAdd As Boolean)
    If pBindingTag.BindingType <> BindType.EventBind Then Exit Sub

    Dim objStr As String = pBindingTag.DataContextBindName
    Dim ctrlStr As String = pBindingTag.ControlBindName

    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(objStr) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(objStr)) Then
        Dim ctrlEvent As Reflection.EventInfo = ctrl.GetType.GetEvent(ctrlStr)

        If Not ctrlEvent Is Nothing Then
            Dim eventDel As [Delegate] = Sub(sender, e)
                                             CallMethod(ctrlStr, sender, e)
                                         End Sub

            Dim convertedDel = CastDelegate(eventDel, ctrlEvent.EventHandlerType)

            ctrlEvent.RemoveEventHandler(ctrl, convertedDel)
            If pDoAdd Then ctrlEvent.AddEventHandler(ctrl, convertedDel)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CastDelegate(source As [Delegate], type As Type) As [Delegate]
    Dim delegates As [Delegate]() = source.GetInvocationList()
    Return [Delegate].CreateDelegate(type, delegates(0).Target, delegates(0).Method)
End Function
```

The article that helped can be found here:
[Casting Delegates](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/07/casting_delegates/)